# Add robustness to model with statsmodel

Tags: python, statsmodels, robustness

I am running a logistic regression with statsmodel and I am trying to add robustness to my model, similar to STATA's `robust` command, and I can't seem to find it on their documentation. Note that **I am not looking for the Robust Linear Regression** with command `sm.RLM()`, as this is another model, not an add-in to the model I want to use.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean robust standard errors? There is a `cov_type` option in `fit` to get sandwich standard errors, HC, cluster, HAC, ...